# Commandments for gentiles

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, noachide-laws, negative-commandments

Would everyone (Jew and gentile alike) benefit by following these commanments?

1. To know there is a G‑d—Exodus 20:2
2. Not to entertain thoughts of other gods besides Him—Exodus 20:3
3. To know that He is one—Deuteronomy 6:4
4. To love Him—Deuteronomy 6:5
5. To fear Him—Deuteronomy 10:20
6. To sanctify His Name—Leviticus 22:32
7. Not to profane His Name—Leviticus 22:32
8. Not to destroy objects associated with His Name—Deuteronomy 12:4
9. To emulate His ways—Deuteronomy 28:9
10. To cleave to those who know Him—Deuteronomy 10:20
11. To love other Jews—Leviticus 19:18
12. To love converts—Deuteronomy 10:19
13. Not to hate fellow Jews—Leviticus 19:17
14. To reprove wrongdoers—Leviticus 19:17
15. Not to embarrass others—Leviticus 19:17
16. Not to oppress the weak—Exodus 22:21
17. Not to gossip about others—Leviticus 19:16
18. Not to take revenge—Leviticus 19:18
19. Not to bear a grudge—Leviticus 19:18
20. To learn Torah and teach it. (Strictly Tanak and mussar for gentiles) Deuteronomy 6:7
21. To honor those who teach and know Torah—Leviticus 19:32
22. Not to inquire into idolatry—Leviticus 19:4
23. Not to follow the whims of your heart or what your eyes see—Numbers 15:39
24. Not to blaspheme—Exodus 22:27
25. Not to worship idols in the manner they are worshiped—Exodus 20:5
26. Not to bow down to idols—Exodus 20:5
27. Not to make an idol for yourself—Exodus 20:4
28. Not to make an idol for others—Leviticus 19:4
29. Not to make human forms even for decorative purposes—Exodus 20:20
30. Not to turn a city to idolatry—Exodus 23:13
31. To burn a city that has turned to idol worship—Deuteronomy 13:17
32. Not to rebuild it as a city—Deuteronomy 13:17
33. Not to derive benefit from it—Deuteronomy 13:18
34. Not to missionize an individual to idol worship—Deuteronomy 13:12
35. Not to love the missionary—Deuteronomy 13:9
36. Not to cease hating the missionary—Deuteronomy 13:9
37. Not to save the missionary—Deuteronomy 13:9
38. Not to say anything in his defense—Deuteronomy 13:9
39. Not to refrain from incriminating him—Deuteronomy 13:9
40. Not to prophesize in the name of idolatry—Deuteronomy 18:20
41. Not to listen to a false prophet—Deuteronomy 13:4
42. Not to prophesize falsely in the name of G‑d—Deuteronomy 18:20
43. Not to be afraid of killing the false prophet—Deuteronomy 18:22
44. Not to swear in the name of an idol—Exodus 23:13
45. Not to perform Ov (medium)--Leviticus 19:31
46. Not to perform Yidoni (magical seer)--Leviticus 19:31
47. Not to pass your children through the fire to Molech—Leviticus 18:21
48. Not to erect a column in a public place of worship—Deuteronomy 16:22
49. Not to bow down on smooth stone—Leviticus 26:1
50. To destroy idols and their accessories—Deuteronomy 12:2
51. Not to derive benefit from idols and their accessories—Deuteronomy 7:26
52. Not to derive benefit from ornaments of idols—Deuteronomy 7:25
53. Not to make a covenant with idolaters—Deuteronomy 7:2
54. Not to show favor to them—Deuteronomy 7:2
55. Not to let them dwell in our land—Exodus 23:33
56. Not to imitate them in customs and clothing—Leviticus 20:23
57. Not to be superstitious—Leviticus 19:26
58. Not to go into a trance to foresee events, etc.--Deuteronomy 18:10
59. Not to engage in astrology—Leviticus 19:26
60. Not to mutter incantations—Deuteronomy 18:11
61. Not to attempt to engage the dead in conversation—Deuteronomy 18:11
62. Not to consult the Ov—Deuteronomy 18:11
63. Not to consult the Yidoni—Deuteronomy 18:11
64. Not to perform acts of magic—Deuteronomy 18:10
65. Men must not wear women's clothing—Deuteronomy 22:5
66. Women must not wear men's clothing—Deuteronomy 22:5
67. Not to tattoo the skin—Leviticus 19:28
68. Not to tear the skin in mourning—Deuteronomy 14:1
69. Not to make a bald spot in mourning—Deuteronomy 14:1
70. To repent and confess wrongdoings—Numbers 5:7
71. To serve the Almighty with prayer daily—Exodus 23:25
72. To bless the Almighty after eating—Deuteronomy 8:10
73. To rest on the seventh day—Exodus 23:12
74. The court must not inflict punishment on Shabbat—Exodus 35:3
75. To afflict and cry out before G‑d in times of catastrophe—Numbers 10:9
76. Not to have relations with women not thus married—Deuteronomy 23:18
77. Not to withhold food, clothing, and sexual relations from your wife—Exodus 21:10
78. To have children with one's wife—Genesis 1:28
79. To fulfill the laws of the woman suspected of adultery (Sotah)--Numbers 5:30
80. Not to have sexual relations with your mother—Leviticus 18:7
81. Not to have sexual relations with your father's wife—Leviticus 18:8
82. Not to have sexual relations with your sister—Leviticus 18:9
83. Not to have sexual relations with your father's wife's daughter (from your father)--Leviticus 18:11
84. Not to have sexual relations with your son's daughter—Leviticus 18:10
85. Not to have sexual relations with your daughter—Leviticus 18:10
86. Not to have sexual relations with your daughter's daughter—Leviticus 18:10
87. Not to marry a woman and her daughter—Leviticus 18:17
88. Not to marry a woman and her son's daughter—Leviticus 18:17
89. Not to marry a woman and her daughter's daughter—Leviticus 18:17
90. Not to have sexual relations with your father's sister—Leviticus 18:12
91. Not to have sexual relations with your mother's sister—Leviticus 18:13
92. Not to have sexual relations with your father's brother's wife—Leviticus 18:14
93. Not to have sexual relations with your son's wife—Leviticus 18:15
94. Not to have sexual relations with your brother's wife—Leviticus 18:16
95. Not to have sexual relations with your wife's sister—Leviticus 18:18
96. A man must not have sexual relations with a beast—Leviticus 18:23
97. A woman must not have sexual relations with a beast—Leviticus 18:23
98. Not to have homosexual sexual relations—Leviticus 18:22
99. Not to have homosexual sexual relations with your father—Leviticus 18:7
100. Not to have homosexual sexual relations with your father's brother—Leviticus 18:14
101. Not to have sexual relations with a married woman—Leviticus 18:20
102. Not to have sexual relations with a menstrually impure woman—Leviticus 18:19
103. Not to castrate any male (including animals)--Leviticus 22:24
104. Not to make pleasurable (sexual) contact with any forbidden woman—Leviticus 18:6
105. To examine the signs of locusts to distinguish between kosher and non-kosher—Leviticus 11:21
106. Not to eat non-kosher animals—Leviticus 11:4
107. Not to eat non-kosher fowl—Leviticus 11:13
108. Not to eat non-kosher fish—Leviticus 11:11
109. Not to eat non-kosher flying insects—Deuteronomy 14:19
110. Not to eat non-kosher creatures that crawl on land—Leviticus 11:41
111. Not to eat non-kosher maggots—Leviticus 11:44
112. Not to eat worms found in fruit once they have left the fruit—Leviticus 11:42
113. Not to eat creatures that live in water other than fish—Leviticus 11:43
114. Not to benefit from a beast condemned to be stoned—Exodus 21:28
115. Not to eat meat of an animal that was mortally wounded—Exodus 22:30
116. Not to eat a limb torn off a living creature—Deuteronomy 12:23
117. Not to eat blood—Leviticus 3:17
118. Not to eat meat and milk cooked together—Exodus 23:19
119. Not to cook meat and milk together—Exodus 34:26
120. To cover the blood (of a slaughtered beast or fowl) with earth—Leviticus 17:13
121. Not to take the mother bird from her children—Deuteronomy 22:6
122. To release the mother bird before taking the children—Deuteronomy 22:7
123. Not to swear falsely in G‑d's Name—Leviticus 19:12
124. Not to take G‑d's Name in vain—Exodus 20:7
125. Not to deny possession of something entrusted to you—Leviticus 19:11
126. Not to swear falsely in denial of a monetary claim—Leviticus 19:11
127. To swear in G‑d's Name to confirm the truth when deemed necessary by court—Deuteronomy 10:20
128. To fulfill what was uttered and to do what was avowed—Deuteronomy 23:24
129. Not to break oaths or vows—Numbers 30:3
130. For oaths and vows annulled, there are the laws of annulling vows explicit in the Torah—Numbers 30:3
131. Not to plant diverse seeds together—Leviticus 19:19
132. Not to plant grains or greens in a vineyard—Deuteronomy 22:9
133. Not to crossbreed animals—Leviticus 19:19
134. Not to work different animals together—Deuteronomy 22:10
135. Not to wear Shatnez, a cloth woven of wool and linen—Deuteronomy 22:11
136. To leave a corner of the field uncut for the poor—Leviticus 19:10
137. Not to reap that corner—Leviticus 19:9
138. To leave gleanings for The poor—Leviticus 19:9
139. Not to gather the gleanings—Leviticus 19:9
140. To leave the gleanings of a vineyard—Leviticus 19:10
141. Not to gather the gleanings of a vineyard—Leviticus 19:10
142. To leave the unformed clusters of grapes for the poor—Leviticus 19:10
143. Not to pick the unformed clusters of grapes—Leviticus 19:10
144. To leave the forgotten sheaves in the field for the poor—Deuteronomy 24:19
145. Not to retrieve them—Deuteronomy 24:19
146. To separate the tithe for the poor—Deuteronomy 14:28
147. To give charity—Deuteronomy 15:11
148. Not to withhold charity from the poor—Deuteronomy 15:7
149. To rest the land during the seventh year by not doing any work which enhances growth—Exodus 34:21
150. Not to work the land during the seventh year—Leviticus 25:4
151. Not to work with trees to produce fruit during that year—Leviticus 25:4
152. Not to reap crops that grow wild that year in the normal manner—Leviticus 25:5
153. Not to gather grapes which grow wild that year in the normal way—Leviticus 25:5
154. To leave free all produce which grew in that year—Exodus 23:11
155. To release all loans during the seventh year—Deuteronomy 15:3
156. Not to pressure or claim from the borrower—Deuteronomy 15:2
157. Not to refrain from lending immediately before the release of the loans for fear of monetary loss—Deuteronomy 15:9
158. Not to work the soil during the fiftieth year—Leviticus 25:11
159. Not to reap in the normal manner that which grows wild in the fiftieth year—Leviticus 25:11
160. Not to pick grapes which grew wild in the normal manner in the fiftieth year—Leviticus 25:11
161. Carry out the laws of sold family properties—Leviticus 25:24
162. Not to withhold payment incurred by any vow—Deuteronomy 23:22
163. Observe the laws of menstrual impurity—Leviticus 15:19
164. Observe the laws of impurity caused by childbirth—Leviticus 12:2
165. Observe the laws of impurity caused by a woman's running issue—Leviticus 15:25
166. Observe the laws of impurity caused by a man's running issue (irregular ejaculation of infected semen)--Leviticus 15:3
167. Observe the laws of impurity caused by a dead beast—Leviticus 11:39
168. Observe the laws of impurity caused by the eight shratzim (rodents, amphibious creatures, and lizards) [specified in the Torah]--Leviticus 11:29
169. Observe the laws of impurity of a seminal emission (regular ejaculation, with normal semen)--Leviticus 15:16
170. Not to accept monetary restitution to atone for the murderer—Numbers 35:31
171. The court must send the accidental murderer to a city of refuge—Numbers 35:25
172. Not to accept monetary restitution instead of being sent to a city of refuge—Numbers 35:32
173. Not to kill the murderer before he stands trial—Numbers 35:12
174. Save someone being pursued even by taking the life of the pursuer—Deuteronomy 25:12
175. Not to pity the pursuer—Numbers 35:12
176. Not to stand idly by if someone's life is in danger—Leviticus 19:16
177. Designate cities of refuge and prepare routes of access—Deuteronomy 19:3
178. To neither work nor plant that river valley—Deuteronomy 21:4
179. Not to allow pitfalls and obstacles to remain on your property—Deuteronomy 22:8
180. Make a guard rail around flat roofs—Deuteronomy 22:8
181. Not to put a stumbling block before a blind man (nor give harmful advice)--Leviticus 19:14
182. Help another remove the load from a beast which can no longer carry it—Exodus 23:5
183. Help others load their beast—Deuteronomy 22:4
184. Not to leave others distraught with their burdens (but to help either load or unload)--Deuteronomy 22:4
185. Buy and sell according to Torah law—Leviticus 25:14
186. Not to overcharge or underpay for an article—Leviticus 25:14
187. Not to insult or harm anybody with words—Leviticus 25:17
188. The courts must carry out the laws of a hired worker and hired guard Exodus 22:9
189. Pay wages on the day they were earned—Deuteronomy 24:15
190. Not to delay payment of wages past the agreed time—Leviticus 19:13
191. The hired worker may eat from the unharvested crops where he works—Deuteronomy 23:25
192. The worker must not eat while on hired time—Deuteronomy 23:26
193. The worker must not take more than he can eat—Deuteronomy 23:25
194. Not to muzzle an ox while plowing—Deuteronomy 25:4
195. The courts must carry out the laws of a borrower—Exodus 22:13
196. Not to curse judges—Exodus 22:27
197. Transgressors must not testify—Exodus 23:1
198. Relatives of the litigants must not testify—Deuteronomy 24:16
199. Not to testify falsely—Exodus 20:13
200. Punish the false witnesses with the same punishment they were seeking for the defendant—Deuteronomy 19:19
201. Not to add to the Torah commandments or their oral explanations—Deuteronomy 13:1
202. Not to diminish from the Torah any commandments, in whole or in part—Deuteronomy 13:1
203. Not to curse your father or mother—Exodus 21:17
204. Not to strike your father or mother—Exodus 21:15
205. Respect your father and mother—Exodus 20:12
206. Fear your father and mother—Leviticus 19:3
207. Not to be a rebellious son—Deuteronomy 21:20
208. Mourn for relatives—Leviticus 10:19
209. Offer peace terms to the inhabitants of a city while holding siege, and treat them according to the Torah if they accept the terms—Deuteronomy 20:10
210. Not to destroy fruit trees even during the siege—Deuteronomy 20:19
211. Prepare latrines outside the army camps—Deuteronomy 23:13
212. Prepare a shovel for each soldier to dig with—Deuteronomy 23:14
213. He who has taken a wife, built a new home, or planted a vineyard is given a year to rejoice with his possessions—Deuteronomy 24:5
214. Not to demand from the above any involvement, communal or military—Deuteronomy 24:5
215. Not to panic and retreat during battle—Deuteronomy 20:3
216. Keep the laws of the captive woman—Deuteronomy 21:11
217. Not to sell her into slavery—Deuteronomy 21:14
218. Not to retain her for servitude after having relations with her—Deuteronomy 21:14

Comment: I would sign a petition to reinstitute breaking the neck of a calf by a stream following an unsolved murder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: No, everyone would not benefit. We are two different people groups with two different relationships with Hashem. Even when Moshiach is here, we will still be different. If someone wants a fuller, deeper relationship with Hashem, they can become a Jew with the 613 mitzvot and everything that comes with it. Otherwise, we serve Hashem as He made us, as Noahides.

Some of those commands can be derived from the 7 Noahide Laws. Some are not obligated to non-Jews and they would receive no spiritual benefit.

The book, The Divine Code, by Rabbi Moshe Weiner deals extensively with this subject.

Here is an [excerpt](https://asknoah.org/faq/going_beyond) from the AskNoah website - they publish the book...

> “6. If a Gentile wants to do one of the other commandments from the Torah [beyond the 7 Noahide Commandments] in order to receive a practical benefit [for himself or for society] (but not as a direct commandment), [he should not be prevented] from doing so, even according to its correct laws for Jews (for example, if he desires to tithe for [proper] charity from his money or produce)… However, if a Gentile observes any of the Jewish commandments from the Torah as a religious obligation (even if he does so from a desire to receive a spiritual reward), this is forbidden based on the prohibition of adding a commandment, and there is no spiritual reward to be derived from this.”

Comment: To repent and confess wrongdoings—Numbers 5:7

To serve the Almighty with prayer daily—Exodus 23:25

To bless the Almighty after eating—Deuteronomy 8:10. None of these are part of the 7 noahide laws. Therefore neither of these commandments would give a gentile spiritual benefit?

Comment: @Miguel I would say yes, there is spiritual benefit to Gentile for these things you mention, but it's limited and I might be wrong. It's difficult to answer this in a concise manner. When a Gentile repents, his transgressions don't become blessings. When a Gentile prays, he doesn't have a priestly obligation to the world. Hashem didn't give us the land. I would say if a Gentile is interested in adding a mitzvot to his life, spend time learning about it from Jewish sources for awhile. Have to shake off cultural assumptions.